# how to auto submit google form if user disconnected in the middle of exam?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I did a fair amount research on how to submit Google Form if the users get disconnected in the middle of the exam. It is not based on time what I want.

The Google Forms do not save the answer. Recently Google introduce it at Google Workspace for Education which can save answers if users disconnected. But I am looking for regular Gmail users.

> What I am trying to do is, I will enable Edit After Submit option. So
> when a user get out of the Form page due to electricity or internet
> issue, the Form will be automatically submitted and then s/he will get an email with a link to edit. Their previous
> response will be saved. Now after the duration of the exam I will stop
> taking responses. How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could interact with Google Form is by `submit`.

So basically you cannot save upon `disconnect`.

You may want to use the `Edit after submit` as you mentioned.

It is available to Regular Gmail users. Could you be specific what is your problem?

---

If you need to auto submit if the user get disconnected. Then you would need a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) and submit with [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#examples)

Google Apps Script

```js
function handleSubmit(formData) {
  const id = 'formId';
  const form = FormApp.openById(id);
  const items = form.getItems();
  const response = form.createResponse();
  Object.keys(formData).forEach(function(key) {
    const i = items[key].asTextItem();
    const r = i.createResponse(formData[key]);
    response.withItemResponse(r);
  });
  response.submit();
  // return response.getEditResponseUrl();
}
```

Web apps

```js
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    google.script.run.handleSubmit(formData);
    return 'Form submitted';
  }
```

Comment: I want to do auto submit if the user get disconnected. So an email will be sent to the user. As the Edit After Submit option is enabled, the user can edit his answers and his previous answer will be saved.

Comment: If then you would need a web apps and submit with `beforeunload`

Comment: How we could do that submit before unload using web apps? Any link for an example?

Comment: Updated. I think I have included all the key lines. Please try your self.